# I am confused as how to use make4ht to execute tex4ht with several command line options, to produce HTML

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

Here are the options I would like to exercise and the various ways I have tried to invoke make4ht:

```
% invocation:
% $ make4ht -c config.cfg notes.tex
% $ make4ht -d notes config.cfg notes.tex
% $ make4ht -d notes notes.tex "config.cfg"

% configuration file config.cfg for make4ht for compilation of notes.tex:
% = sections in separate HTML page
% = HTML section files named according to section title
% = footnotes at the end of each file instead of stand-alone pages
% = CSS sets maximum width of page

\Preamble{xhtml,2,sec-filename,fn-in}
\Css{body{max-width:72ch;margin:1em auto;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: Can you clarify again what is the question exactly? What is the problem. I read your question 3 times and do not understand what is the problem or what you need help with.  The command line options for make4ht are given in https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/support/make4ht/make4ht-doc.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make4ht` expects parameters in the form of:

```
$ make4ht [make4ht options] filename "tex4ht.sty options" "tex4ht_options" "t4ht_options" "latex_options"
```

So, everything before filename should be `make4ht` option. It can be either short option (`-c`), or long option (`--config`). So, if you want to use output directory and config file, you should use:

```
$ make4ht -c config.cfg -d notes notes.tex
```

Alternativelly, you can pass config file in `tex4ht.sty options`, but you need to pass it without the `.cfg` extension:

```
$ make4ht -d notes notes.tex "config"
```

This version doesn't work:

```
$ make4ht -d notes notes.tex "config.cfg"
```